# Converting DICOM files to JPEG files for use in Inception V3

Tags: tensorflow, image-processing, imagenet, medical-imaging

I am trying to use the Inception V3 model on a set of medical data images. The problem is the data is in DICOM format and can't be used with the Image classifier. Can anyone please let me know how to use the DICOM files directly with the Inception V3 classifier.

P.s. - I learnt to use the classifier by a tutorial provided by TensorFlow and am relatively new at this.

Comment: Not familiar with most of the terms in your question, but if you are on Linux, you probably have **ImageMagick** and can convert DICOM images to JPEG with `convert input.dcm output.jpg`.

Comment: I don't think your question has anything to do with tensorflow, by the way, pydicom is what you are looking for

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
import os
import dicom
import matplotlib.image as image

os.chdir("path/to/dicom.dcm")
dicom_file = dicom.read_file("dicom.dcm")
dicom_array = dicom_file.pixel_array
image.imsave("dicom.jpg", dicom_array)
```

Comment: Some explanation of why this code works would be useful.

Comment: Does not work on python 3.7